# Boton para cambiar el tamaño de las fuentes del body

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas he conseguido este código pero no quiero que sea tipo seleccionador o lista simplemente quiero dos botones uno que aumente el tamaño de la fuente del body y otro que disminuya.

Tengo hecho el boton pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer para que aumente, os dejo el codigo entero.(Soy un principiante).

```js
function CambioTexto(){
  var e=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  var x=document.getElementById("valor");
  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    if (x.options[x.selectedIndex].text=="elige"){
      return false
    }
    e[i].style.fontSize=x.options[x.selectedIndex].text+"px";
    e[i].style.fontFamily="Arial";
    e[i].style.color="#000000";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
Botones
<input type="button" name="aumentar" value="aumentar" onclick="CambioTexto">


Selecciona un tamaño:
<select id="valor" onchange="CambioTexto()">
<option>elige</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>25</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>35</option>
<option>40</option>
</select>

<p>Si no lees bien el texto . . .</p>

<div>
<p>TEXTO QUE QUIERAS</p>
<p>TEXTO QUE QUIERAS</p>
<p>TEXTO QUE QUIERAS</p>
<p>TEXTO QUE QUIERAS</p>
<p>TEXTO QUE QUIERAS</p>
<p>TEXTO QUE QUIERAS</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No es muy diferente a lo que ya tienes, simplemente necesitas crear los dos botones y asignarle el evento `onclick` y pasarle el operador(+/-).

Dicho esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera.

```js
//Todos los elementos a los que les vamos a cambiar el fontSize
const elementsList = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

function getElementFontSize(element){
  //getComputedStyle nos devuelve las propiedades css de cada párrafo(elemento)
  const elementFontSize = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  return parseFloat(elementFontSize);  //Devolvemos el total de pixeles
}

function cambiarTexto(operador) {
   for(let element of elementsList) {
     //Obtener el total de pixel de cada párrafo.
     const currentSize = getElementFontSize(element);
     
     //Restar o sumar, dependiendo del operador.
     const newFontSize = (operador === '+' ? (currentSize + 1) : (currentSize - 1)) + 'px';
     //Aplicarle al parrafo actual el nuevo tamaño.
     element.style.fontSize = newFontSize
   }
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="return cambiarTexto('+')">+</button>
  <button onclick="return cambiarTexto('-')">-</button>
  
  <p>Este texto mola!!!</p>
  <p>Este texto mola!!!</p>
  <p>Este texto mola!!!</p>
  <p>Este texto mola!!!</p>
```

Comment: Gracias tio me ha funcionado en la pagina todas la p al menos aumentan de tamaño:)

Comment: También puedes utilizar [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) por si quieres hacerlo en cualquier elemento. Me alegro que te haya servido.

Answer (score 2):

Con este código se hace lo que pides, simplemente hice dos funciones una para cada botón y sumé y resté según se pulse.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
var num = 12;
function CambioTextoMayor(){
  num = num + 1;
  var font=parseInt(num);
  document.getElementById('texto').style.fontSize=font+"px";
}
function CambioTextoMenor(){
  num = num - 1;
  var font=parseInt(num);
  document.getElementById('texto').style.fontSize=font+"px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Botones
<input type="button" value="aumentar" onclick="CambioTextoMayor();">
<input type="button" value="aumentar" onclick="CambioTextoMenor();">


<p id="texto">Si no lees bien el texto . . .</p>

</body>
</html>
```